# Rails routing error no route matches?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

Environment: VM with Ubuntu and latest versions of Rails and ruby installed

Application controller code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_current_user
  protected # prevents method from being invoked by a route
  def set_current_user
    debugger
    # we exploit the fact that find_by_id(nil) returns nil
    @current_user ||= Moviegoer.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
    redirect_to login_path and return unless @current_user
  end
end
```

used debugger `@current_user` is null as expected but the redirect statement is failing "No route match"

Routes.rb code:

```
get  'auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#create',:as => :login
post 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
get  'auth/failure' => 'sessions#failure'
```

The error:

```
Error: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"create"}):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:8:in `set_current_user'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the routes specified,login_path expects an arguement, a value for 'provider' in auth/:provider/callback

Comment: Also it seems as though the "and return" is redundant since there is no code following it whose execution you want to prevent. Also find_by_id is deprecated - better to use where(:id => session[:user_id).first OR better yet execute a plain old find(session[:user_id]) if session.key?(:user_id)